# How to choose an attribute of a child element as a SelectedValuePath in a ComboBox in WPF?

Tags: c#, wpf

I have a ComboBox where I need to do this:

```
     <ComboBox x:Name="CitySelectComboBox" SelectedValuePath="Text">
            <b:Interaction.Triggers>
                <b:EventTrigger EventName="Loaded">
                    <b:InvokeCommandAction Command="{Binding DownloadWeatherCommand}"
                            CommandParameter="{Binding ElementName=CitySelectComboBox, Path=SelectedValue}" />
                </b:EventTrigger>
                <b:EventTrigger EventName="SelectionChanged">
                    <b:InvokeCommandAction Command="{Binding DownloadWeatherCommand}"
                            CommandParameter="{Binding ElementName=CitySelectComboBox, Path=SelectedValue}" />
                </b:EventTrigger>
            </b:Interaction.Triggers>

            <ComboBoxItem IsSelected="True">
                    <TextBlock Text="Praha"/>
            </ComboBoxItem>
            <ComboBoxItem>
                    <TextBlock Text="Brno"/>
            </ComboBoxItem>
    </ComboBox>
```

As you can see, I am trying to access the `Text` property of `Textblock` inside the `ComboBoxItem`. Just putting `Text` does not work as I get the following error:

`BindingExpression path error: 'Text' property not found on 'object' ''ComboBoxItem' (Name='')'.`

I need to find out how to specify the path to this property in the `SelectedValuePath` but no online resources have been helpful. The code otherwise works if I include the city names inside the `ComboBoxItem` as  `<ComboBoxItem Content="Praha"/>`, but I need to take the name from the child element `TextBlock`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`SelectedValuePath` targets the `SelectedItem`, which is a `ComboBoxItem` in your case. `ComboBoxItem` does not have a `Text` property.

The `TextBlock` is assigned to the `ComboBoxItem.Content` property.
The valid property path is therefore `"Content.Text"`:

```xml
<ComboBox SelectedValuePath="Content.Text">
  <ComboBoxItem IsSelected="True">
    <TextBlock Text="Praha" />
  </ComboBoxItem>
  <ComboBoxItem>
    <TextBlock Text="Brno" />
  </ComboBoxItem>
</ComboBox>
```

Because the `ComboBoxItem` (or `ContentPresenter` to be precise) will create a `TextBlock` implicitly in case the `Content` value is a `string`, defining a `TextBlock` explicitly is redundant.
Instead set the `Content` property directly. This reduces code and enhances the readability of your code:

```xml
<ComboBox SelectedValuePath="Content">
  <ComboBoxItem IsSelected="True"
                Content="Praha" />

  <!-- Alternative content property syntax -->
  <ComboBoxItem>Brno</ComboBoxItem>
</ComboBox>
```